# Attach data element to tkinter Listbox element

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I am using tkinter with python 3.2

I am making an audio tag editor, and need a way to display the audio files after the user imports them. I am using a `Listbox` to do this. For the string I am passing into the `insert` method, I am using the file name, but I need a way to store the full path. It needs to be associated with the list element it corresponds to, so that when the user selects the element, I can look at the file using the full path and display the current audio tags for editing.
[image: Diagram of links between elements and data]

Is there a way to make this kind of association, so that every list element points to a data structure of some sort (string containing the file path in this example)? I can trigger the logic to access it with a binding on the `listbox` itself, but I need to know how to associate the data structure with each list element.

Comment: just use a dictionary?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#dict, keys are filenames in listbox and values are full path, `dict` is great for association.

Comment: For that I would need a way to find out the text from the selected list element.

Comment: and `Listbox.get` wouldn't work because....?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't know that existed.

Comment: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get more information on the methods of the listbox you can [use this reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/listbox.html).

You can use a `dict` to associate the file names to their full paths:

```
files_to_show = {os.path.basename(name):name 
                      for name in FULL_PATHS_SOURCE}
```

then on the listbox you can use the `.curselection()` to get the indices of the current selection then the `.get()` method to get the text for each entry:

```
(listbox.get(i) for i in listbox.curselection())
```

then to get the full path just look it up in the dict:

```
selected_full_paths = [files_to_show[listbox.get(i)]
                        for i in listbox.curselection()]
```

or more verbosely:

```
selected_full_paths = []
for selected_i in listbox.curselection():
    selected_text = listbox.get(i)
    full_path = files_to_show[selected_text]
    selected_full_paths.append(full_path)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the code samples are a little hard to understand. Can you update them to make the syntax a little clearer?

Comment: I added a verbose version of the final list comprehension separating each step, although I don't find the list comprehension too hard to understand personally.

Comment: it is simply using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and dict comprehension